# Get average day or week values

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, timestamp

I have statistical data like this:

```
time        val1
1424166578  51
1424166877  55
1424167178  57
1424167477  57
```

`time` is a unix timestamp. There is one record every 5 minutes excluding nights and sundays. This continues over several weeks.

Now I want to get these values for an average day and an average week. The result should include values for every 5 minutes like normal but for average past days or weeks.

The result should look like this:

```
time    val1
0       43.423
300     46.635
600     51.887
...
```

So time could be a timestamp with relative time since day or week start. Perhaps it is better to use `DATETIME`... not sure.

If I use `GROUP BY FROM_UNIXTIME(time, '%Y%m%d')` for example I get one value for the whole day. But I want all average values for all days.

Comment: try `GROUP BY  FROM_UNIXTIME(`time`, '%d.%m.%Y')`

Comment: This makes no difference to my code and still gives me only one value for every day.

Comment: Can you clarify?What d o you mean for a whole day?Something like SUM(val1)...GROUP BY FROM_UNIXTIME(time, '%d.%m.%Y' ?

Comment: Do you want moving/sliding averages with the window size equal to 1 day or 1 week?

Comment: OK so you want, for example `14:45:00 -> 43.423` where 42.423 is the average for `14:45 - 14:50` for every day in past 7 days?

Comment: I don't know how to clarifiy it but I try it. I can easyly few a single day. I get all values from that day and order it, so I can create a chart for example. Now I want not only that single day, I want the average day. Alle existing data for a day but the values are average values for all days. Did you get it?

Comment: @Michael see revised answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be interested in grouping dates by five minute intervals instead of dates. This is fairly straightforward:

```sql
SELECT
    HOUR(FROM_UNIXTIME(time)) AS HH,
    (MINUTE(FROM_UNIXTIME(time)) DIV 5) * 5 AS MM,
    AVG(val1) AS VAL
FROM your_table
WHERE time > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL 7 DAY)
GROUP BY HH, MM
```

The following result will explain how date is clamped:

```
time        FROM_UNIXTIME(time)  HH  MM
1424166578  2015-02-17 14:49:38  14  45
1424166877  2015-02-17 14:54:37  14  50
1424167178  2015-02-17 14:59:38  14  55
1424167477  2015-02-17 15:04:37  15  00
```

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this as:

```
select date(from_unixtime(time)) as day, avg(val)
from table t
group by date(from_unixtime(time))
order by day;
```

Although you can use the format argument, I think of that more for converting the value to a string than to a date/time.